# Keyboard size for iPhone 6 Plus with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, keyboard, native, iphone-6-plus

Looks like a stupid issue but after hours of search and tests, I can't find a solution. I'm adapting an existing app developed with PhoneGap for the iPhone 6 Plus and all is fine except keyboard. On iPhone 6 Plus, the keyboard is magnified/zoomed but I can't display the native keyboard in a webview. Below is the problem:

[Comparison picture between zoomed and native keyboard on iPhone 6 Plus](http://snoop-adventures.com/misc/keyboard_comparison.jpg)

As you can see, on the left, keyboard is big. One the right, it is smaller or in other words, native. Is there a way to solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: How did you fix this?